# Percentage of requests SQL

Tags: sql

So, I have this table:

```
Table1
|Number | abc |
|100    | No |
|200    | No |
|300    | Yes |
|400    | No  |
|500    | No  |
```

What I want is the percentage of values that is "yes". In this case, the desired OUTPUT is `20%`

I thought that by dividing the number of "yes" by the total number It would do it, but i can't "join" all things.

I know that the number of "yes" is

```
select count(abc) 
from table1
where abc='yes'
```

And the total number is

```
select count(*)
from table1
```

How do i get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query that works in all SQL engines is

```
select sum(case when abc = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) * 100 / count(*)
from your_table
```

Comment: The first case worked, although the second (more simple) didn't work :ERROR: function sum(boolean) does not exist . However, if I can't find any simpler, will use the first one!

Comment: As noted in the answer the second query works if you use MySQL which you don't as I see now. I remove it to avoid confusion.